# Blender crashing on Soft Body Simulator

Tags: soft-body

I'm doing a soft body simulation on a grass model that I made. The settings that I changed from the default are the Mass, Soft Body Goal (Default & Damping amount), Stiffness and collision. Here's the [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30833).

Whenever I tried 'bake all dynamics', Blender froze and crashed all the time. Maybe my computer's not very strong. But is there any settings on the soft body that I can change in order to ease the baking for my computer?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably don't have enough RAM; How much do you have?

Comment: 4Gb in my computer

Comment: And what about the Ram that Blender is allowed to use?

Comment: If you are using a 32bit system, Blender is able to only use 2GB per app by default. It takes 10 minutes to open the file on my computer (i7, 8GB RAM), so I am sure we can optimize it.

Comment: The short answer is the softbody simulator is not designed to simulate a mesh with this much complexity. Can you describe what you are trying to achieve? I feel like a hair system will be so much better suited for this.

Comment: I would just like to animate the grass and I needed it to be soft body in order for it to be affected by wind.